# using recursion for changing the data structure into a different format

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

how can i use loadash for the below data structure and get the desired output.

i am using the logic of index of array in this recursion, since the terms property will be a an array of single element.

```js
let data = {
  users: [
    {
      terms: ["service|/users"],
      conditions: ["view", 'create']
    },
    {
      terms: ["service|/users-details"],
      conditions: ["view"]
    },
    {
      terms: ["service|/usersNew"],
      conditions: ["view"]
    },
    {
      terms: ["list|searchuser"],
      conditions: ["view"]
    },
    {
      terms: ["list|createuser"],
      conditions: ["view", "create"]
    },
    {
      terms: ["service|/user-contacts"],
      conditions: ["view"]
    },
    {
      terms: ["service|/user-location"],
      conditions: ["view"]
    },
    {
      terms: ["page|supplierlist|button|select"],
      conditions: ["enable"]
    },
    {
      terms:["page|supplierlist|button|create-new"],
      conditions: ["disable"]
    }
  ]
};


class Mapper{
  constructor(data){
    this.currentIndex = -1;
    this.data = this.extractData(data);
  }

  resolveData(terms, object={}, conditions){
    try{
      return terms.reduce((result, string) => {
        const [key, value] = string.split(/\|(.+)/);
        if (value && value.includes('|')) {
          result[key] = result[key] || {};
          this.resolveData([value], result[key], conditions);
        } else {
          result[key] = result[key] || [];
          this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex + 1;
          result[key].push({ [value]: conditions[this.currentIndex] });
        }
        return result;
      }, object);
    }catch(error){
      throw error
    }
  }


  extractData(data){
    try{
      let terms = data.users.map(o => o.terms)
      terms = [].concat(...terms);
      const conditions = data.users.map(o => o.conditions);
      return this.resolveData(terms, {}, conditions)
    }catch(error){
      throw error
    }
  }
}


const result = new Mapper(data)

console.log(result)
```

Is there any better way to optimize the above logic by use of lodash. Should i use recursion for this problem ?

Any help appreciated

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Its a little dense but if it works its not that bad.

Comment: do you have always a single item in the arrays?

Comment: terms will be  a single item in an array but conditions can be multiple

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested hash table and use an iteratove and recursive approach for the keys/terms.

```js
var data = { users: [{ terms: ["service|/users"], conditions: ["view", 'create'] }, { terms: ["service|/users-details"], conditions: ["view"] }, { terms: ["service|/usersNew"], conditions: ["view"] }, { terms: ["list|searchuser"], conditions: ["view"] }, { terms: ["list|createuser"], conditions: ["view", "create"] }, { terms: ["service|/user-contacts"], conditions: ["view"] }, { terms: ["service|/user-location"], conditions: ["view"] }, { terms: ["page|supplierlist|button|select"], conditions: ["enable"] }, { terms: ["page|supplierlist|button|create-new"], conditions: ["disable"] }] },
    hash = { _: [] },
    result;

data.users.forEach(({ terms: { 0: terms }, conditions }) => {
    terms.split('|').reduce((r, k) => {
        if (!r[k]) {
            r[k] = { _: [] };
            r._.push({ [k]: r[k]._ });
        }
        return r[k];
    }, hash)._.push(...conditions);
});

result = { currentIndex: data.users.length - 1, data: Object.assign({}, ...hash._) };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: the page is an object as expected but here its an array of objects

Comment: if its an array of objects i need to do a  loop again to access it. But using recursion i was able to get it properly